# An error occurred in generating C# code with xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I am trying to generate C# code from the xsd with xsd.exe.
The xsd is http://www.omg.org/spec/SACM/20120501/Argumentation.xsd.
I am sure that I should locate and specify including files.
I did so.
But I have some errors (attribute "id" not declared, element Extension not declared etc...)

Could you help me on it?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) addin to to that.